# Dos command to list top level directories and their sizes

Tags: recursion, directory, size, dos

I'm looking for a DOS command that will list the directories and files at the top level of the C drive, and list their complete sizes (ie by recursive analysis - but only return top level sizes).

Is there something I can run on the command line to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the trick to this is to fire up cygwin and run

```
du -k . | egrep -v "\./.*/.*" | sort -n
```